# is there a free bug tracking system that does not have to be installed and set up

Tags: bug-tracking

I know this question has been asked before but I am looking for bugtracking system that is free and is just online.

We are not looking for anything fancy, just want the test team to be able to log something so that testers can go back and go through the bugs.

I've looked at bugzilla but it has to be installed and the installation seems very long. Basically looking for something quick and dirty...

Comment: How many users do you need, and for how many projects? Some commercial offerings are free for one project and a few users

Comment: How quick and how dirty?  There's always Excel.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Code](http://code.google.com/). It's for open source projects, so your bugs will be visible, but it is free to use.

Also [this](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=free+hosted+bug+tracking&btnG=Search).

Answer (score 2):

If this is a class project (e.g., a university course project), you can get a free [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBugz/) account for the duration of the project. Joel has mentioned it several times on the [Stack Overflow Podcast](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html). I only suggested this because you didn't give any details about what type of project you are working on. This may not apply to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

you could always create your own using google docs.

Comment: +1 Interesting idea. There's built-in sharing, revision history, graphs, etc.

Comment: ya exactly.  I use google spreadsheets for putting down brainstorming ideas with my team.  Like you said...built-in sharing, revision history, graphs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We use [veoproject.com](http://www.veoproject.com) to track our bugs.  It's a fully-featured project management system, but works great for our needs.  They have a basic free account that works really well.

Answer (score 0):

I like [BugHost](http://www.bughost.com/).